# pyspark : TypeError: element in array element in array element in array field prediction: ArrayType(FloatType,true) can not accept object

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for advice to resolve a `TypeError` when operating on the entire PySpark DataFrame.

I have a PySpark DataFrame with the following schema and I want to apply further operations like count() or show() to the DataFrame then convert the Spark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame. As you can see below, the error being returned when performing `.count()` on the PySpark DataFrame is as follows

```
TypeError: element in array element in array element in array field prediction: ArrayType(FloatType,true) can not accept object -1.2425838708877563 in type <class 'float'>
```

I am able to successfully display the first row from the Pandas DataFrame, using `.head()`, after converting the PySpark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello friendo, would you mind avoiding the usage of pictures. Just show us your pyspark sample dataframe, and show us your pandas df. And tell us what is wrong, from what i can see you are losing the df indexes correct?